# PHP self-hosted photo and video sharing apps?

Tags: php, photo-gallery, video-gallery

I march with the first and best Mardi Gras parade of the season in New Orleans, [Krewe du Vieux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krewe_du_Vieux).

I want to help my Krewe out by hosting and setting up a members only photo-sharing and video sharing app.

I can definitely write this if I have to but I am hoping someone has done that for me.

Open source is preferred but licensed is ok too.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bigger task than you think it is, especially since there are so many excellent existing solutions out there, plus many free third-party-hosted services that offer password control.  Check out [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) for instance.

Comment: Thanks!  Installing now.  Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

try out this free joomla component, its called "com_contushdvideoshare"
its a good component for video gallery, u can upload videos to your server or geta link from youtube, members can upload and u publish those videos,
am using it on www.zendmedia.co.ug/features

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can get an wordpress theme that you like for that..

allow entry for members only and give all your members admin access.

Not the best solution but a decent one.

edit:
gallery offered by DJ looks better